# From Mysql query output to retrieve files in the file system and rename the files

Tags: bash, shell, filenames, mysql, sql

I have to call a SQL query from bash that outputs 1000 rows of two columns

1. File_Path (Eg., `/opt/files/dest/2.bin`)
2. Name_of_the_file (Eg., `fax attachment.pdf`, `invoice.docx`... yes, there are spaces).

The file name in the server file system is in different naming format eg: 1.bin, 22.bin. There are <1000 unique files exactly as some are missing.

Here is the Snapshot of the SQL query:

```
Select * from datafileinfo limit 4;
```

Output:

```
FILEID,NAME 
/ran/file/MM/2012/04/3.bin,new_fax.pdf
/ran/file/MM/2013/06/12.bin,new_report.docx
/ran/file/MISC/2012/08/212.bin,daily_transact.jrxml
/ran/file/MONY/2013/04/122.bin,NULL
```

As a first step, I gathered all those files and put it in a temporary folder.

But I couldn't able to rename the files as I have to lookup the 'Name of the file' with corresponding 'File Path'. Is there any way I can perform the job?

Comment: Consider modifying your post to clean up the formatting so it is more easily readable. The first paragraph in particular is a little rough to understand.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. Can you show some sample rows of output, and what you want to do with it?

Comment: This should be pretty simple to do with sed/awk, can you post a snippet of a SELECT query from the table so we can see the exact syntax.

Comment: Thanks! @HalosGhost for editing my post. I just added the snapshot of the SQL query above.

Comment: @Chandra, what?

Answer (score 0):

1. Change IFS separator to ","
2. Iterate while loop over mysql query result
3. Extract dir from old path
4. Perform renaming

The code will be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS=','
mysql ...executequery... | while read oldpath newfname
do
  filedir=$(dirname $oldpath)
  mv "$oldpath" "$filedir/$newfname"
done
```

You didn't mention what to do with NULL query results.

Comment: Thanks @tomasz-myrta for providing the solution. The one with the NULL values I can name differently. I think that is straight forward.